# ListView doesn't listens to OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have the following code in my app:

```
                        AnotherCursorAdapter adapter = new AnotherCursorAdapter(CadItemActivity.this, 
                                                                                R.layout.imgsinternas, 
                                                                                cursorImagens, 
                                                                                new String[] {"nome", "tags",},
                                                                                new int[] { R.id.txtNome, R.id.txtTags });
                        telaScroll.setAdapter(adapter);


    telaScroll.setClickable(true);
    telaScroll.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
            Log.d("1212121", "OnClick"); 
            // return false;
        }
    });
```

Code for AnotherCursorAdapter:

```
public class AnotherCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public AnotherCursorAdapter(Context context, 
                                int layout, 
                                Cursor c,
                                String[] from, 
                                int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
             // get the views from the row
             TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
             TextView tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);
             ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.figura);
            //asign the values
             name.setText(cursor.getString(4)); 
             tags.setText(cursor.getString(3)); 

             name.setClickable(true);
             tags.setClickable(true);
             img.setClickable(true);


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imgsinternas, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

telaScroll is a ListView populated by my database. I am not extending from ListActivity.

The code above DOESN'T work!

The event is not being triggered!

What am I doing wrong? =(

Comment: r u using custom adapter? what are the view your list having. i.e is your list has button with click listener?

Comment: hello baya! thanks for answering. I am using a custom adapter and my listview is a list with a imageview and a text. they are inflated. I set them both to be android:clickable="true" but it didn't help. I want to click in the image (maybe the textview, too) and get their info. Can you help me, please?

Comment: can paste more code than i can see what is wrong with this

Comment: Hello Khan, I just added more code. Any help is appreciated! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting onClickListener for  your text and/or image in your list item while binding.

```
@Override     
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {              
    // get the views from the row         
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);         
    TextView tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);          
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.figura);        
    //asign the values          
    name.setText(cursor.getString(4));              
    tags.setText(cursor.getString(3));            
    name.setClickable(true);          
    tags.setClickable(true);           
    img.setClickable(true);

    name.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()) {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // code for performing action on click
        }
    });

    img.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()) {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // code for performing action on click
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to check if your row layouts and views, which you are inflating in getView are not clickable and focusable.

Comment: Hello, my friend. Thanks for answering. Yes, all my items are clickable and focusable = "true". Any ideas? =)

Comment: change these items clciable=false; as you cant listen for events when you click on these items

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent tutorial for [listview with several clickable area](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525) written by Cyril Mottier. I strongly recommend you to take a look.

Your current problem occurs because of the buttons which take the focus from the listitem.

Answer (score 0):

your are code is right, maybe  other view over the listview，and you can't touch the listview.

Comment: I don't think so, since I can scroll through the ListView, so it seems I can touch it.

Comment: HI: this link [listview demo](http://bigcateasymorse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/androidlistviewdemo0.1/) is a list demo .i think you are adapter code have some errors . you should use getView method replace bindview and newView method.